# Modifying a string with letters, parentheses and numbers

Tags: javascript, replace

How can I modify this string:

```
"SRID=4326;POINT (-21.93038619999993 64.1444948)"
```

so it will return

```
"-21.93038619999993 64.1444948"
```

(and then I can split that)?

The numbers in the string can be different.

I've tried using .replace & split, but I couldn't get it to work properly. How can I make this happen using Javascript?

Comment: What format is this?!

Comment: `/\(([^)]+)\)/`

Comment: @JonasW. my friend is storing data with this format... custom I think

Comment: @reyni tell him to do it differently. Something like JSON or any other known data format.

Comment: to answer the followup; after you get the values, you can `str.split(" ");` to split the numbers on `space`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `match` and regex:

```
"SRID=4326;POINT (-21.93038619999993 64.1444948)".match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]

// "-21.93038619999993 64.1444948"
```

Comment: because there would not be a duplicate of such a question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not good using REGEXP but this could be a solution with pure `split`.

Hope it helps :>

```js
var str = "SRID=4326;POINT (-21.93038619999993 64.1444948)" ;
var newStr = str.split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_string = string.replace("SRID=4326;POINT (", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). The first number is put in `first`, the second number is put in `second`.

```js
const INPUT = "SRID=4326;POINT (-21.93038619999993 64.1444948)";
const REGEX = /SRID=\d+;POINT \((.+) (.+)\)/

const [_, first, second] = INPUT.match(REGEX);

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```